# Vue.js + Nuxt.js - Why is my computed property undefined when I unit test a head() method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue.js + Nuxt.js component with a [`head()`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/) method:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'my-page',
        head() {
            return { title: `${this.currentPage}` };
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

`currentPage` is a computed property.

When I run my application, the component runs correctly and it sets the page title to the right value.

When I run this code from a Jest + Vue Test Utils unit test, the code fails however:

```
it('should set the title to "my page"', () => {

    const options = {
        computed:{
            currentPage: () => {
                return 'My Title';
            }
        }
    };

    const target = shallowMount(MyPage, options);

    const actual = target.vm.$options.head();

    expect(actual.title).to.equal("My Title");

});
```

The test fails with the message:

> AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'My Title'

Why is the computed property undefined even though I mock it?

Does the fact that I invoke the `head()` method through `target.vm.$options` have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass context into your head call.

`const actual = target.vm.$options.head.call(target.vm);`

Comment: This was doing my head in... Many thanks for this solution.